# DCS - User specifc push notifications

Tags: icalendar, caldav

I am trying to get user specific push notifications working.

I followed thread : https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/calendarserver-users/2010-August/001649.html

However, I do not understand how does user specific notifications get pushed. Thread above does not discuss any user specific configuration.

Please provide some details.

Updated:

- What I am trying to accomplish is "For iOS users, push notifications for any changes for that user on server side"
- User specific : "Push notifications for a user....means user1 receives new email on server...push notify user1....."
- I tried following thread above along with http://svn.calendarserver.org/repository/calendarserver/CalendarServer/trunk/doc/Extensions/caldav-pubsubdiscovery.txt
- But I could put everything together.
- I was hoping for some documentaion or blog describing the process to accomplish push notifications.

Maybe its my lack of understanding of the push notifications with DCS that I can not ask the right question.

If I am still not clear...please leave a comment and I will delete the question.

Comment: I don't think there are any user-specific notifications for that specific feature.

Comment: @Evert Could you please tell what is that feature for? I understand you wrote DCS...also please point me to any example for user specific push notifications... I am trying to get push notifications working with DCS...any pointer will be helpful

Comment: This question does not provide enough detail. What do you want to accomplish? What did you try? Do you really want to configure XMPP push or APS? What do you mean by 'user specific'?

Comment: I didn't write it. The feature you linked has to do with sending notifications via the xmpp protocol, which can be used for subscribers to get live updates. As @hnh said, if that's not what you're looking for, you'll have do better describing what you want to do.